# Listar postagem de usuário logado

Tags: php, mysqli

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou fazendo um sistema onde o usuário pode se cadastrar e cadastrar e fazer postagens, é um sistema de blogs. Montei o usuário com SESSION e consigo exibir somente os dados dele. No meu banco de dados tenho a tabela usuários, onde ficam seus dados e a tabela postagens. O que quero saber agora, é como eu consigo listar no perfil do usuário, somente as postagens que ele fez, pois do jeito que fiz até agora, quando exibo as postagens aparecem as postagens de todos os usuários cadastrados. Eis o meu código e obrigado a quem ajudar.

Minha tabela onde exibo a lista de postagens

```
 <table>
      <?php
      $postagens = listaPostagens($conexao);
      foreach($postagens as $postagem) {
    ?>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <img src="envios/<?=$postagem['img']?>"/>
          </td>
          <td>
            </span><?=$postagem['localizacao']?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$postagem['texto']?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$postagem['visualizacoes']?>
          </td>
          <td>
           <?=$postagem['curtidas']?>
          </td>
          <td>
            <?=$postagem['compartilhamentos']?>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }
    ?>
    </table>
  </section>
  <?php
```

Função que lista as postagens:

```
  function listaPostagens($conexao) {

    $postagens = [];
    $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from postagens");
    while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
      array_push($postagens, $postagem);
    }
    return $postagens;
  }
```

Como eu disse, desta forma eu estou selecionando as postagens de todos os usuários e preciso de ajuda para listar as postagens somente do usuário logado no momento.

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from postagens WHERE idusuario = {$variavelcontendoIDdousuario}");`, substitua a coluna `idusuario` pela respectiva coluna na sua tabela do banco de dados e a variável `$variavelcontendoIDdousuario` pelo valor do id do usuário.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simples amigo, você irá usar a cláusula `where` do `mysql`, na sua function.

```
function listaPostagemDoUsuario($conexao, $id){
 $postagens = [];
 $query = mysqli_query($conexao, "select * from postagens where idUsuario = {$id}");
 while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   array_push($postagens, $postagem);
 }
 return $postagens;
}
```

a query `select * from postagens where idUsuario = {$id}`, diz o seguinte: me retorne todas as postagem do usuário com o seguinte id, agora é só você editar para o nome do campo que você colocou certinho.

Comment: Então, @RickPariz fiz a alteração na função, mas está dando o seguinte erro Notice: Undefined variable: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\toqve\interno\profile.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\toqve\interno\funcoes.php on line 63

Comment: a linha 63 é while($postagem = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {

Comment: e a linha 10 é onde listo: $postagens = listaPostagens($conexao, $id);

Comment: @FrancisVagnerdaLuz, você está passando o id do usuário corretamente para a função ? altere o idUsuário na query, para o nome do campo que guarda o id do usuário na sua tabela

Comment: Valeu @RickPariz, consegui resolver aqui... valeu mesmo!

Comment: mano, que bom eu ter conseguido ajudar, poderia marcar minha resposta como a certa ?

Comment: tem sim @RickPariz... mas onde eu faço isso?...rs.

Comment: em baixo dos pontos da resposta, que fica no canto esquerdo dela, tem tipo um V, é só você clicar nele